# With the mongoDB C# driver, how do I execute a runCommand with args?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a (for me) very complex mongo query, something like this:

```
public void GetData(ObjectId projectId, IList<ObjectId> users)
{
    var query = @"
    db.getCollection("users").aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        projectId: projectId,
        userId: { $in: [...users] },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { document: '$document', subject: '$subject' },
        context: { $push: { context: '$context' } },
        category: { $first: '$Category' }
      },
    }])";
    var items = this.Database.Db.RunCommand<Object>(query);
    ...
}
```

Here there is a `projectId` and a `users` parameter of this method. tries to found those documents where the projectId equals to the given value, and the userId is any of the given values. When I rewrite to C# fluent style it looks somehow like this:

```
public void GetData(ObjectId projectId, IList<ObjectId> users)
{
 var items = this.Database.Users
  .Aggregate()
  .Match(p => p.projectId  == projectId && users.Contains(p.user))
  /*
  .Group( p => new {document= p.Document, subject=p.Subject},
     // p => new { ???  }
     // ?????
     // )
  */
  .ToList();
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not experienced enough to continue writing the `.Group(..)` part (especially with the `$push` in it) and this is only a little part of a whole query with another `Group()`s and some `Unwind()`s and some `Project()`s later, therefore I decided to use it as-is, and apply the `RunCommand()`.

But I do not know how to use the `RunCommand()` with arguments, or ... should I generate the query string included the current values instead?

How to solve the problem? What do you suggest me to continue? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using RunCommand here, instead you can:

1. Put `$group` stage arguments you want just as raw strings (`.Group("..", "..")`). Mongo driver allows implicit creating required arguments from string. See example with $match and $project stages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77553160/9492730).
2. You can always use AppendStage (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395490/how-to-use-raw-mongodb-aggregation-query-in-c)). Where you can provide the whole $group stage as string. Something like: `.AppendStage("{ '$group': { '_id' ..`