MongoDB driver Linq Last operation not supported
I am using MongoDB driver 2.19.0. In Mongo collection, document has 1 list of statuses and I want to sort all documents based on the last element of statuses list.
So sort query is
orderbyquery = s => s.Application.StatusHistory.Last().ApplicationStatus

filteredCollection = _collection
 .Find(searchquery)
 .Sort(Builders<Application>.Sort.Descending(orderbyquery))
 .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Limit(pageSize).ToList();

The error says

An unexpected error occurred:
MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException: Expression not
supported: s.Application.StatusHistory.Last().

How can I do sorting based on last element inside list for all documents?

try latest driver, but if it still throws, then you will have to implement it via raw mql https://www.knowi.com/blog/the-best-introduction-to-mongodb-query-language-mql/ and when you will have working query, use it in c# like I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77872449/with-the-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-how-do-i-execute-a-runcommand-with-args
